# continue foreach loop from dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, foreach, dispatcher

I have a foreach loop and I've used dispatcher inside it and I have another foreach inside it. I want to continue first foreach after checking the results.

```
bool isNude = false;
var SearchTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    foreach (var file in await GetFileListAsync(GlobalData.Config.DataPath))
    {
        isNude = false;
        if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                if (ButtonNude.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    foreach (var itemx in nudeData)
                    {
                        if (itemx.Equals(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName)))
                        {
                            isNude = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isNude)
                    continue;

            }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
    }
}, ct);
```

But the continue is not available how can i do this?

Comment: Since it's a lambda expression there is no `continue`, replace it with `return`. But the continue won't have any effect on your program as it is at the moment, as there isn't anything after the continue you could skip.

Comment: @TobiasTengler after continue exist some codes that i didnt write, if i use return, Will it go to the next item in the foreach?

Comment: It will continue with the next item in the outer foreach (`var file`) or more precisely it will continue after the await statement and then jump to the next item.

Comment: @TobiasTengler tnx bro my problem fixed, if you want sent it as an answer so i can check it as answer

Comment: I added it as the answer. Glad I could help you out. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, your lambda for `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` doesn't know it's being called in a loop, so therefor there is no `continue` available. You need to use `return` to exit the awaited task, so your code can continue after the awaited task.

```
bool isNude = false;
var SearchTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    foreach (var file in await GetFileListAsync(GlobalData.Config.DataPath))
    {
        isNude = false;
        if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                if (ButtonNude.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    foreach (var itemx in nudeData)
                    {
                        if (itemx.Equals(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName)))
                        {
                            isNude = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isNude)
                    return; // continue -> return

                // other code
                }, DispatcherPriority.Background);

                // <--- code continues here after return
            }
    }
}, ct);
```